# MongoDB unique index on date field

Tags: mongodb

I tried the following

```
db.Wall.ensureIndex({event_time : 1}, {unique: true})
```

but this output keep showing

```
{
    "err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index: scrap.Wall.$event_time_1  dup key: { : new Date(0) }",
    "code" : 11000,
    "n" : 0,
    "connectionId" : 10,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

I try getIndexes but the event_time doesn't show in there

Comment: If you've got duplicate values in `event_time` in your collection at the moment, you won't be able to create a unique index.

Comment: Looks like the duplicate values are dates(0) if you were using Date(0) to indicate the Date hasn't been set yet, you're better off not setting that to 0 but to null and then you can use unique sparse index to enforce that set dates must be unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't create an index with duplicate values as shown. One easy method for finding the duplicate values, is to use an [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/) query, from the MongoDB shell, such as:

```
db.Wall.aggregate([
       {$group : { _id: "$event_time" ,  count : { $sum: 1}}},
       {$match : { count : { $gt : 1 } }} ])
```

That will return a list of all `event_time` values that were present in more than one `Wall` document.

Explanation:

1. groups on `event_time` (`_id: "$event_time"`)
2. for each group of `event_time` (a unique time), adds one to the count (`count: { $sum: 1}`)
3. Then, only matches those groups where the `count` is greater than 1

Then, you can decide how pervasive the problem is. You can `find` all of the matching by filling in the `event_time` value in a `find` as shown below. Of course, it won't be super fast it's not yet indexed. :)

```
db.Wall.find({ 'event_time' : /* one of the event times */ })
```

And of course, you could just forcibly delete duplicates (`dropDups`) as shown in another answer. However, the results may seem non-deterministic as it will keep only the first document it finds during the indexing phase and all others will be removed.

Answer (score 3):

If data in `wall` collection is not sensitive you can invoke:

```
db.Wall.ensureIndex({event_time : 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

But **all duplicates** will be **removed permanently**!